# Image watermarking with Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have application , where django is at serverside. Plus I do have jquery at UI.
I have an image display , where user can enter some text to watermark the image.

Is it possible to use JQuery to watermark the displayed image and create a new image out of that ?

EDIT: I can't use `<canvas>` , for previous versions browser support

Thanks
Jijoy

Comment: On client side? And then what are you doing with the image? Uploading back?

Comment: nope. It allows the user to save the image. That's it .

Comment: I don't see that happening...

Answer (score 1):

You can, but probably not in the way that you're thinking. Any manipulation to the image you do on the client side with jQuery is a *preview of changes*. Your client code will have to keep track of these changes and then send commands to execute on the server. The server receives the commands and applies the commands to the image that already exists on the server. 
You then reply with the updated image in your response.

I've done this on [one of my sites](http://resizeimage.org), although I deal with resizing instead of watermarking the principle is the same. Feel free to check out the jQuery.